# 2019 link error - c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, linker-errors

I wrote the following code snippet in VS2010:

```
#pragma once
#include "stdafx.h"
#ifndef SECURITY_WIN32
#define SECURITY_WIN32
#endif
#include "windows.h"
#include "sspi.h"

int main( void )
{
    ULONG cPackages = 0;
    PSecPkgInfo pInfo = NULL;
    SECURITY_STATUS stat = EnumerateSecurityPackages(&cPackages, &pInfo);
    if (stat == SEC_E_OK) 
    { 
        for (ULONG i = 0; i < cPackages; i++) 
        { 
            wprintf(L"%s\t%s\n",pInfo[i].Name, pInfo[i].Comment); 
        } 
        FreeContextBuffer(pInfo); 
    } 
    return 0; 

}
```

but, at the compile time I got the following errors:

> error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   _*imp*_EnumerateSecurityPackagesW@8 referenced in function _main

and

> error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _FreeContextBuffer@4
>   referenced in function _main

can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to link against `Secur32.lib`.

Go to `Project Properties -> Linker -> Input` and add `Secur32.lib` in the list.

Answer (score 2):

Linking errors "unresolved external symbol", generally, mean that there were no required library (libraries) added to resolve the symbol. In VC++ case you get the symbol without decoration `FreeContextBuffer` (which will be the function missed), go to http://msdn.microsoft.com and search for this function's related article. In this case it will produce ["FreeContextBuffer"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms906515.aspx) as a first result. You then look  for the last section "Requirements" and find out what headers would be needed for compiler and libraries (your case) for linker- Secur32.lib. Then, add this library in IDE's *Properties -> Linker -> Input*. Or with `#pragma comment()` directive in code. 
Hope this will help.

Comment: Not really, it could also mean unimplemented functions, or wrong use of import/export directives.

Comment: Oh yes, but these are "advanced" causes, that imply the programmer already knows what library is needed. Anyway, i will add "generally" to the answer.

Comment: I know the causes that I mentioned weren't the source, but it was also wrong saying the error means one thing when it can mean more. The new version of the answer is much more correct. +1

Answer (score 0):

```
#include "stdafx.h"
```

was meant for including 'system' interfaces, it's likely that windows.h it's already included. So try to move your #define inside the stdafx.h, before any other include.